# C++, Reducing the amount of repeated code in a Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: c++, rock-paper-scissors

I feel like my code has way too much for what it is, this is my first project and would love to learn some tips in making code more efficient for the future, any other tips for my code here would be greatly appreciated.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    // yn = yes / no
    string yn;
    cout << "Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors? (Enter: y or n) ";
    cin >> yn;
    if (yn == "y")
    {
        // rps = rock paper scissors
        string rps;
        cout << "Choose, Rock, Paper, or Scissors\n";
        cin >> rps;
        if (rps == "Rock")
        {
            // This outputs one of three choices and tells you if you've won, lost, or drew.          
            // rpslist is just the array list
            // rpsnumber is just a random number to pick from the array 
            rock:
            string rpslist[3] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors " };
            int rpsnumber = rand() % 3;
            cout << "I choose: " << rpslist[rpsnumber];            
            if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Rock")
            {
                // One of three options here, win / lost / drew and a loop if you want to play again
                // yna = yes or no, a is because the "Rock" option comes first, and b, c follows after
                string yna;
                cout << ", we draw! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> yna;
                if (yna == "y") goto rock;
                else (yna == "n"); goto exit;

            }
            else if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Paper")
            {
                string yna;
                cout << ", you lose! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> yna;
                if (yna == "y") goto rock;
                else (yna == "n"); goto exit;

            }
            else if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Scissors");
            {
                string yna;
                cout << ", you win! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> yna;
                if (yna == "y") goto rock;
                else (yna == "n"); goto exit;

            }
        }
        else if (rps == "Paper")
        {   
            paper:
            string rpslist[] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
            int rpsnumber = rand() % 3;
            cout << rpslist[rpsnumber];

            if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Rock")
            {
                string ynb;
                cout << ", you win! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> ynb;
                if (ynb == "y") goto paper;
                else (ynb == "n"); goto exit;

            }
            else if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Paper")
            {
                string ynb;
                cout << ", we draw! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> ynb;
                if (ynb == "y") goto paper;
                else (ynb == "n"); goto exit;


            }
            else if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Scissors");
            {
                string ynb;
                cout << ", you lose! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> ynb;
                if (ynb == "y") goto paper;
                else (ynb == "n"); goto exit;

            }
        }
        else if (rps == "Scissors")
        {
            scissors:
            srand(time(0));
            string rpslist[] = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
            int rpsnumber = rand() % 3;
            cout << rpslist[rpsnumber];
            if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Rock")
            {
                string ync;
                cout << ", you lose! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> ync;
                if (ync == "y") goto scissors;
                else (ync == "n"); goto exit;

            }
            else if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Paper")
            {
                string ync;
                cout << ", you win! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> ync;
                if (ync == "y") goto scissors;
                else (ync == "n"); goto exit;

            }
            else if (rpslist[rpsnumber] == "Scissors");
            {
                string ync;
                cout << ", we draw! Do you want to play again? (Enter: y or n) ";
                cin >> ync;
                if (ync == "y") goto scissors;
                else (ync == "n"); goto exit;

            }
        }
    }

    else yn == "n";
    exit:
    {
        exit;
    }
}


```
````

Comment: Have you learned about functions yet, that generally reduces the repetition in the code.

Comment: @BCdotWEB We have at least 132 rock-paper-scissors questions, I think most of the good titles are taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The include statements are a weird mix of C++ and C header files. Use `<chrono>` for time, and use `<random>` for random functions.
2. `using namespace std;` is generally frowned upon. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice
3. Again, use C++ STL random facilities instead of `srand` and `rand`.
4. Don't use `goto`. You hardly need it nowadays, if ever. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto
5. Prefer using `std::array` to C-style arrays. It is just as performant, and allows you to utilize value semantics and STL iterator-based algorithms.
6. You're creating `rpslist` in every conditional block. Instead, just create it once at the start, and keep using that.

A lot of this code can be avoided using functions. Think about how control 'flows', and structure your program accordingly. You functions judiciously; make sure each function does one task only, and does it well. If a function is getting too big, identify parts which can be separated from it and put them into their own functions.

Answer (score 3):

(In addition to the [accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/241413/188857))

We can first extract some commonly used code snippets in functions.  Let's start with confirmation:

```
bool confirm_continue()
{
    std::cout << "Do you want to play again (y/n)? ";

    for (std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);) {
        if (input == "y") {
            return true;
        } else if (input == "n") {
            return false;
        }

        std::cout << "Invalid input.  Do you want to play again (y/n)? ";
    }

    throw std::runtime_error{"Failed to read input"};
}
```

Note that invalid inputs are handled properly.

Then, the winning criteria:

```
enum class Choice { rock, paper, scissors };

enum class Result { draw, win, lose };

void evaluate(Choice user_choice, Choice computer_choice)
{
    static const std::map<Result, std::string_view> messages {
        { Result::draw, "It's a draw." },
        { Result::win, "You won." },
        { Result::lose, "You lost." }
    };

    auto result = static_cast<Result>(
        (static_cast<int>(user_choice) - static_cast<int>(computer_choice) + 3) % 3
    );
    std::cout << messages.at(result) << '\n';
}
```

Choice input:

```
Choice input_choice()
{
    static const std::map<std::string_view, Choice> table {
        { "rock"    , Choice::rock     },
        { "paper"   , Choice::paper    },
        { "scissors", Choice::scissors }
    };

    std::cout << "Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): ";
    for (std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);) {
        if (auto it = table.find(input); it != table.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Invalid input.  Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): ";
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error{"Failed to read input"};
}
```

We can also use a choice generator:

```
Choice generate_choice()
{
    static std::mt19937 engine{std::random_device{}()};

    std::uniform_int_distribution dist{0, 2};
    return static_cast<Choice>(dist(engine));
}
```

Now the hard-to-follow structure with `goto`s can be improved by writing code that reflects the logic of the game:

```
do {
    auto user_choice = input_choice();
    auto computer_choice = generate_choice();

    show_choice(computer_choice);
    evaluate(user_choice, computer_choice);
} while (confirm_continue());
```

---

Putting everything together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

enum class Choice { rock, paper, scissors };

enum class Result { draw, win, lose };

void evaluate(Choice user_choice, Choice computer_choice)
{
    static const std::map<Result, std::string_view> messages {
        { Result::draw, "It's a draw." },
        { Result::win, "You won." },
        { Result::lose, "You lost." }
    };

    auto result = static_cast<Result>(
        (static_cast<int>(user_choice) - static_cast<int>(computer_choice) + 3) % 3
    );
    std::cout << messages.at(result) << '\n';
}

bool confirm_continue()
{
    std::cout << "Do you want to play again (y/n)? ";

    for (std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);) {
        if (input == "y") {
            return true;
        } else if (input == "n") {
            return false;
        }

        std::cout << "Invalid input.  Do you want to play again (y/n)? ";
    }

    throw std::runtime_error{"Failed to read input"};
}

Choice generate_choice()
{
    static std::mt19937 engine{std::random_device{}()};

    std::uniform_int_distribution dist{0, 2};
    return static_cast<Choice>(dist(engine));
}

Choice input_choice()
{
    static const std::map<std::string_view, Choice> table {
        { "rock"    , Choice::rock     },
        { "paper"   , Choice::paper    },
        { "scissors", Choice::scissors }
    };

    std::cout << "Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): ";
    for (std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);) {
        if (auto it = table.find(input); it != table.end()) {
            return it->second;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Invalid input.  Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): ";
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error{"Failed to read input"};
}

void show_choice(Choice choice)
{
    static const std::map<Choice, std::string_view> table {
        { Choice::rock    , "rock"     },
        { Choice::paper   , "paper"    },
        { Choice::scissors, "scissors" }
    };
    std::cout << "I chose " << table.at(choice) << ".\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors.\n";

    do {
        auto user_choice = input_choice();
        auto computer_choice = generate_choice();

        show_choice(computer_choice);
        evaluate(user_choice, computer_choice);
    } while (confirm_continue());
}
```

Example session:

```
Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors.
Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): rock
I chose scissors.
You won.
Do you want to play again (y/n)? y
Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): scissors
I chose rock.
You lost.
Do you want to play again (y/n)? y
Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): paper
I chose scissors.
You lost.
Do you want to play again (y/n)? n
```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/mrF-md); the output is a mess because of non-interactive stdin)

Comment: Thanks alot for this, I didnt expect anyone to put this much effort into a response, I am sure to take notes of this for later projects, thank you again :)